# How to allow specific devices for App Store?

Tags: app-store, swift4, augmented-reality, xcode9, arkit

I'm going to be submitting an ARKit application soon and on Apple's guidelines they say [Offer AR features only on capable devices](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/technologies/augmented-reality/).

How do I go on and do that? Because when I submit to the App Store, won't it just be out for everyone and then it may crash for people who's devices don't support ARKit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Had to go into the info.plist and in Required Device Capabilities, I added "arkit".